# Why does the Scala compiler prefer to infer an argument of value null as Array[Char] instead of Object?

Tags: java, scala, interop, null, overloading

Consider these methods from `java.lang.String`

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the <code>Object</code> argument.
 *
 * @param   obj   an <code>Object</code>.
 * @return  if the argument is <code>null</code>, then a string equal to
 *          <code>"null"</code>; otherwise, the value of
 *          <code>obj.toString()</code> is returned.
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}

/**
 * Returns the string representation of the <code>char</code> array
 * argument. The contents of the character array are copied; subsequent
 * modification of the character array does not affect the newly
 * created string.
 *
 * @param   data   a <code>char</code> array.
 * @return  a newly allocated string representing the same sequence of
 *          characters contained in the character array argument.
 */
public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
    return new String(data);
}
```

and this Scala code

```
val result = String.valueOf(null)
```

which results in

```
String.valueOf(null)
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:193)
  at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2852)
```

It works if you annotate `null` with any other type except `Array[Char]`.

Why does the Scala compiler seem to prefer `Array[Char]` to `Object` considering that `Array` is effectively final and can't be overridden and is invariant in its element type (so the chance that this usage is intended is quite small)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array[Char]` is preferred to `Object` because it's more specific. If something can be converted to types X or Y, and there's a conversion from X *to* Y, then X is more specific than Y... and X is effectively preferred over Y when it comes to overloads.

At least, that's assuming Scala is like Java in terms of overload resolution, which I strongly expect it is.

It should be easy to avoid though - just cast the null reference to `Object`, to make the overload taking `Array[Char]` non-applicable.

EDIT: Okay, having looked at the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) *briefly* it's a little more complicated than that, but I believe the basic premise is the same. See p97 in the previous link for all the gory details.

Comment: I assume you mean "can be converted to" as "is a subtype of" and not as something with an implicit conversion in scope? Because `null` is a value of type `Null` which is a subtype of any reference type and `Array[Char]` is a subclass of `Object` it just decides that the array fits better? ... I guess then the real problem is the naming here. `valueOf(char[])` should really have a different name, because it does something different. Does C# have the same problem as it basically copied all the things Java had back in the old days (and `java.lang.String` exists since JDK 1.0)?

Comment: @soc: Java and .NET have fairly different String classes. Indeed, there are plenty of libraries which are different between .NET and Java, and have been since 1.0. There are certainly plenty of similarities in the languages, but it's not quick as simple as you're making it out to be.

Comment: By "can be converted to" I mean "is compatible with" by the looks of it, in Scala terminology. From the spec: "The null value is of type scala.Null, and is thus compatible with every reference
type."